# send a photo from C++ server to android phone

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I need to send a photo from C++ server to android phone
my photo is loaded using open cv libray , I received it in android but I could not put it in a bitmap form to show it in android phone
my server code look like this

```
void sendMat(Mat m , SOCKET client) //send an Image to the cleint called client
char chNum[1];
chNum[0] = m.channels();
send(client , chNum , 1 , 0);
if(m.channels() == 1)
{
char *buf = new char[m.cols * m.rows];
for(int i = 0 ; i < m.rows ; i++)
    for(int j = 0 ; j < m.cols ; j++)
      buf[i*m.cols+j] = m.at<char>(i,j); 
for(int i = 0 ; i < m.cols * m.rows ; i++)
    cout << (int)buf[i] << endl;
send(client , buf , m.rows*m.cols , 0);

}
else  //m.channels == 3
{
    char *buf[3];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
        buf[i] = new char[m.rows * m.cols];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < m.rows ; i++)
        for(int j = 0 ; j < m.cols ; j++)
        {
            buf[0][i*m.cols+j] = m.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0];
            buf[1][i*m.cols+j] = m.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[1];
            buf[2][i*m.cols+j] = m.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2];
        }
    send(client , buf [0], m.rows*m.cols , 0);
    send(client , buf [1], m.rows*m.cols , 0);
    send(client , buf [2], m.rows*m.cols , 0);


}
```

}

my client code is like this

```
client = new Socket("10.0.2.2" , 2222);
                    OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
                    InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
                    int img[] = recData(in , chN);
                    This.im = Bitmap.createBitmap(img, WIDTH, HEGIHT, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

my problem is how to implement this method (recData) 
I tried many ways but i failed

Comment: Since all you send is the raw image bytes, how do you know on the receiving side how big your image is?

Comment: Iam using  fixed dimensions

Comment: I think you should post some of your failed attempts at writing recData. You should also say how they failed, did they fail to compile, did they crash when they ran, did they run but show the wrong image etc. Basically the more information you can give the more chance you will get a helpful answer. Start with the single channel case since that's the simplest.